# Cannot install BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, conda

Pretty straight forward. I type in:

`conda install bs4`

and it doesn't install.

Last time I tried it, it attempted to install for about 3 hours and then stopped. I would just like to know if anyone else had this problem, and if so, if they were able to solve it.

Comment: "it attempted for about 3 hours" - wow, are you running this on a literal potato?  O_0 Jokes aside, are you able to install any other packages? How much time does it take to start up the Python interpreter? How fast is your Internet connection?

Comment: It keeps on saying there is conflicts within the file and then will try an alternative solution. I don't know how to solve this. Every other package has worked for me. i dont think its the internet as it takes very little time start the interpretor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing a conda package and you receive a conflict error, there can be many causes. You have a few choices:

1. Create a new environment including the problem package and any packages
   that caused the conflict (shorter)
2. You can try to troubleshoot the current environment (longer)

   check for any pip installs

   check conda config --show

   check conda info

   etc

I suggest #1, trying to create a new environment with the bs4 package and the other packages mentioned in your conflict and see if this can be resolved given your conda configuration, etc.

```
conda create --name testing bs4 numpy pandas
```

and so on

Comment: I mostly agree, though what is list in the troubleshooting wouldn’t be preventing upgrades/installs. Instead, try checking the package’s specific dependencies (find by [searching Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=bs4)) and comparing them to the current packages, then manually updating each to see what won’t budge. Your answer could be improved by leading with creating a new env - that is the idiomatic way to work with Conda when one has a project with new requirements.

Comment: @merv, good suggestions. I reversed the order of the suggestions. Also, in the past when i see conflicts like this, I usually only see the top level listed. Trying to fix those will usually expose other lower level conflicts. I suspect the conflict is in one of the lower level/hidden dependencies.